# How does Python3 compare floats when using `set`?

Tags: python, floating-point, set

The `set` function in Python relies on the existence of a robust equality operator existing on the elements given to `set`.

Suppose we had a list of floating point numbers, `xs`, and we called `set(xs)`. How will `set` compare the elements of `xs`? Will it check to see if two elements are within machine epsilon, or will it perform bitwise equality?

Comment: Equal to machine epsilon means bitwise equality.

Comment: Except stuff like nans

Comment: hash-based containers use `__eq__` to compare equality, so it boils down to "how is equality implemented for `float` objects"

Comment: Can you clarify what makes you think ``set`` would use *any* tolerance for checking ``float`` values? Are you aware how sets work, i.e. that they require consistent ``__hash__`` and ``__eq__`` of their elements?

Comment: As with most Python built-ins, you can define your own `set` subclass that does what you want.